# How can I create a firebase user from the node.js client

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

How can I create a firebase user from the node.js client? I see that there is a simple-login but that looks to be used from the web browser. I would like to authenticate with my firebase secret and then call the createuser api somehow.

The way my system is built the clients only send requests to the backend for processing. This way I have a log of every action taken by every user and I can guarantee that each alteration is applied to my other databases as well before it makes it into firebase. Also I do not want users to be able to create other users. Firebase is just a workqueue for me mostly but I am also using the simple login to verify the user then swapping them over to a login token afterwards to get the ability to check custom permissions in the auth on security rules.

Comment: Currently there is no way to create simple login users from node.js.

Comment: What is your use case for using Firebase Simple Login from a Node.js environment? If you already have a server process running, it looks like the standard way to auth, [Custom Login](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/custom-login.html) would be more appropriate here.

Comment: I want to control user creation deletion and password resets from the server. I do not want the client to be able to create more users

Comment: Tim, check out Custom Login, as @RobDiMarco suggested. I think you'll find this a much better fit.

Comment: I have a simple use case for wanting Firebase Simple Login from a node.js server.... Suppose I want to grant access to my firebase to a third party service. With Custom Login, I have to give them my secret, so there is no way I can restrict access. Sure they can log in as a user, but they have the secret, so they could get access to everything if they want.

Comment: Another use case for SimpleLogin from Node : Testing.  I want to be able to test account creation and signup using Mocha.  Right now, it seems that's not possible.  I also want to test my app with Mocha.  I need to be able to login as a test user.

Comment: I really need to be able to generate firebase users from node. My user's client is not my app, it is a 3rd party app that installs my app as a plugin. They call my 'install' api end point via oauth. So at that point I need to auto create their account server side and then flow the user back to the 3rd party system.

Comment: How long do firebase custom tokens live for?